# javascript | click + mousemove for Android

Tags: javascript, html, css, android-browser

I have a slider that works user `drag` it.
It works well on computers. but nothing happen in mobile browser.

So I want to  handle drag by `touches` in mobile phones.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd most likely want to use `touchstart` `touchmove` and `touchend`. Other mouse events like `click` will still work.

Comment: I tried 
    document.body.ontouchmove  = function(){
        console.log("it's worked");
    }
but no result in chrome mobile browser

Comment: I don't believe `.ontouchmove` is a function. Try `document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function() { console.log("it's worked") })`